# Website that goes to the content where user left off

Tags: html, css

In HTML and CSS, how to make something that when user sees a page and leaves it and reopens it the page will be loaded in the last focused paragraph by the user?

Comment: it's the browser that takes care of that. Or, you can target a paragraf in the url if u set an ID to the element and point to it in the URL with `#target`. Chrome has a feature if u mark a piece of text, highlight it, right click and "Copy link to highlight".

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with only HTML and CSS. But it's possible with front-end JavaScript and cookies.

Periodically save [`scrollTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) and [`scrollLeft`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft) of the main content element to document cookie. When document loads, parse the cookie and restore the scrolling with the [`scrollTo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo) method.